# Puppeteer. Exist page goto link slow than create new page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, puppeteer, cpu-usage

The problem is i create **50 page (Tab)**. And each page i **go to** another **link** after that, i go to **another link** again, but time to get to new link is really **slow than** if i close current page and make a new page to use.
Is that should be or have another way. Close and create new page use too much CPU use (alway 100%).
Example 1: SLOW TAKE 2 second to leave when finish a job

```
const session1 = await currentPage.target().createCDPSession();
await session1.send('Page.enable');
await session1.send('Page.setWebLifecycleState', { state: 'active' });
await currentPage.goto(link, { timeout: 0 });
// SOME JOB
// 50 tab - 4249 link => 8968.557s to complete (30% CPU, 1.5GB RAM)
```

Example 2: FAST TAKE 0.5~1 second to leave when finish a job. BUT USE 100% CPU

```
const session1 = await currentPage.target().createCDPSession();
await session1.send('Page.enable');
await session1.send('Page.setWebLifecycleState', { state: 'active' });
await currentPage.goto(link, { timeout: 0 });
// SOME JOB
await currentPage.close()
// Then create new one
// 50 tab - 4249 link => 2066.062s to complete (100% CPU, 1.5GB RAM)
```

What should i do to impove my code? Because i don't want to use that much CPU.